# HTML5 file api - can't drag/drop over flex app in Firefox on Windows

Tags: html, apache-flex, firefox, file-upload, drag-and-drop

So here's the setup. I have a flex application which fills the entire browser window and I'd like to give users the option to drop files anywhere on the app to upload the file to my server. Or just as good, send the contents of that file to the app itself. For reference my current setup is very close to that which is outlined [here](http://thunderheadxpler.blogspot.com/2012/03/dnd-file-using-html5-into-flex-web-app.html).

I've got an absolutely positioned, transparent, div which fills the entire screen and sits above the flex content acting as my drop zone.

There have been no issues in all browsers I've tried that support the file api **except** Firefox on Windows. In this instance, as soon as the file is dragged over the flex content my cursor turns into a null symbol and all drag/drop events are suppressed.

I've got the latest versions of Firefox and Flash Player, Windows is 7 Pro 64-bit (though this doesn't seem to matter as I've tried it on a number of different Windows machines). Firefox on mac has no issues.

I've tried a few different scenarios to no avail:

- Using an iframe for the drop zone
- Giving the dropzone an image background (transparent png)

However, if the drop zone is not transparent - all is well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Firefox bug.

You could try and set the div to be slightly less than transparent using css opacity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For the moment I'm working around the issue using [flex-iframe](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/) to pull in a drop zone and just not having it always be available (i.e. user needs to enter an "upload" dialogue to see the *non-transparent* drop zone). I'll give this a try once I have a free moment and report back.